# How to remove excess td when using loop javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am going to generate a table with td colspan.

```
for(let x = 0; x < rows; x++){
  table += "<tr>";
  for(let y=0; y < cols; y++){
    if(x == 1 && y == 2) {
      table += `<td colspan="3">${y}</td>`;
    } else {
      table += `<td>${y}</td>`;
    } 
  }
  table += "</tr>";
}
```

The problem is when I merge cells using colspan, there is an excess of columns.

https://jsfiddle.net/jL8dq1rg/

How can remove excess column (5,6) so that the columns will be even?

**Note:** The x & y values are dynamic so as with the colspan. Meaning, any row could have a colspan.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may for example skip the columns counter when the cell spanning is encountered.

But I see in the meanwhile a similar answer was already delivered.

```js
var table = '';
const rows = 5;
const cols = 6;

for(let x = 0; x < rows; x++){
  table += "<tr>";
  for(let y=0; y < cols; y++){
    //if 2nd row and 3rd column,
    if(x == 1 && y == 2) {
      //set the cell data to span 3 columns
      table += `<td colspan="3">${y}</td>`;
      y+=2; //<---- increment the cols counter skipping the cols this cell is spanning across
    } else {
      table += `<td>${y}</td>`;
    } 
  }
  table += "</tr>";
}

document.getElementById('target')
  .innerHTML = table;
```

```css
table td{
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<table id="target"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let x = 0; x < rows; x++){
  table += "<tr>";
  for(let y=0; y < cols; y++){
    if(x == 1 && y == 2) {
      table += `<td colspan="3">${y}</td>`;
      y+=2 //y+2 End cycle early
    } else {
      table += `<td>${y}</td>`;
    } 
  }
  table += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: along with sharing solution, pls add relevant information for people visiting this question can understand

Answer (score 0):

You could work with the "y" variable of your for-loop and add +2 to your variable whenever you add a colspan.

```
const rows = 5;
const cols = 7;

let table = "<table border='1'>";
for(let x = 0; x < rows; x++){
    table += "<tr>";
  for(let y=0; y < cols; y++){
    if(x == 1 && y == 2) {
      table += `<td colspan="3">${y}</td>`;

      y += 2

    } else {
        table += `<td>${y}</td>`;
    } 
  }
  table += "</tr>";
}

table += "</table>";

document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = table;
```